# MIPS assembly writing a function from a very specific description

Tags: function, assembly, mips

I have this specific description of how to write a function called `tim2string` , I have written this function but I'm unsure if I'm doing as it's Say's in the description. I have tried to run my code on MARS and I get this `ERROR`.NOTE the `tim2string` is added in the end of code.

```
timetemplate.asm line 99: Runtime exception at 0x00400118: address out of range 0x00005958
```

**The description of function is the following**

Name: The subroutine must be called time2string.
Parameters (two): Register $a0 contains the address of an area in memory, suitably large for the
output from time2string . The 16 least significant bits of register $a1 contains time-info, organized
as four NBCD-coded digits of 4 bits each. All other bits in register $a1 can have any value and must
be ignored.

Example: register $a0 can contain the address 0x100100017 , and register $a1 can contain the value 0x00001653.
Return value: None.
Required action:

The following sequence of six characters must be written to the area in memory
pointed to by register $a0 .

1) Two ASCII-coded digits showing the number of minutes, according to the two more
significant NBCD-coded digits of the input parameter. Example: '1', '6' (ASCII 0x31, 0x36):

2) A colon character (ASCII : , code 0x3A).

3) Two ASCII-coded digits showing the number of seconds, according to the two less
significant NBCD-coded digits of the input parameter. Example: '5', '3' (ASCII 0x35, 0x33).
4. A null byte (ASCII NUL, code 0x00).
Notes:You must use the function hexasc to convert each NBCD-coded digit into the corresponding
ASCII code. Use the sb instruction to store each byte at the destination. The macros PUSH and POP
are useful for saving and restoring registers.

```
  # timetemplate.asm
  # Written 2015 by F Lundevall
  # Copyright abandonded - this file is in the public domain.
.macro  PUSH (%reg)
    addi    $sp,$sp,-4
    sw  %reg,0($sp)
.end_macro

.macro  POP (%reg)
    lw  %reg,0($sp)
    addi    $sp,$sp,4
.end_macro

    .data
    .align 2
mytime: .word 0x5957
timstr: .ascii "text more text lots of text\0"
    .text
main:
    # print timstr
    la  $a0,timstr
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    nop
    # wait a little
    li  $a0,2
    jal delay
    nop
    # call tick
    la  $a0,mytime
    jal tick
    nop
    # call your function time2string
    la  $a0,timstr
    la  $t0,mytime
    lw  $a1,0($t0) #load the adress contained in $t0 into $a1
    jal time2string
    nop
    # print a newline
    li  $a0,10
    li  $v0,11
    syscall
    nop
    # go back and do it all again
    j   main
    nop
# tick: update time pointed to by $a0
tick:   lw  $t0,0($a0)  # get time
    addiu   $t0,$t0,1      # increase
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf # check lowest digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa # if digit < a, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x6     # adjust lowest digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf0    # check next digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x60    # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa0    # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf00   # check minute digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0xa00   # if digit < a, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0x600      # adjust digit
    andi    $t1,$t0,0xf000  # check last digit
    sltiu   $t2,$t1,0x6000  # if digit < 6, okay
    bnez    $t2,tiend
    nop
    addiu   $t0,$t0,0xa000  # adjust last digit
tiend:  sw  $t0,0($a0)      # save updated result
    jr  $ra                 # return
    nop

  # you can write your code for subroutine "hexasc" and  below this line
  #
hexasc:  
    andi    $a0,$a0,0xf       #only 4 least significant bits ignore other bits  
    addi    $v0,$zero,0x30    #$v0 = 0x30 ('0')
    addi    $t0,$zero,0x9     #t0 = 0x9

    ble     $a0,$t0,L1        #branch if a0 <= 0x9
    nop
    addi    $v0,$v0,0x7       #v0 = v0 +0x7

   L1:
    add     $v0,$a0,$v0       #v0 = V0 +a0
    jr      $ra
    nop
 delay:
    jr      $ra
    nop

 time2string:
    PUSH    ($t2)           
    PUSH    ($t0)
    PUSH    ($a1)

    lb      $t0, 0($a1)      #load one byte from a1     "LINE 99" ERROR
    andi    $t2, $t0,0xf     #check the 4 lowest bits ignore other
    jal     hexasc           # call hexasc
    nop
    sb      $t0, 0($a1)      #stor back that byte in a1


    lb      $t0, 1($a1)      # load the next byte
    andi    $t2, $t0,0xf0
    jal     hexasc
    nop
    sb      $t0, 1($a1)


    lb  $t0, 2($a1)
    andi    $t2, $t0,0xf00
    jal hexasc
    nop
    sb  $t0, 2($a1)


    lb  $t0, 3($a1)
    andi    $t2, $t0,0xf000
    jal hexasc
    nop
    sb  $t0, 3($a1)


    POP ($a1)
    POP ($t0)
    POP ($t2)


    jr  $ra
    nop
```

**Update 1.0**

I had some progress to written `time2string` function i have come so far 
and still i need some help.
I single step through my code it's working fine until this line`sb  $v0, 0($t0)     #stor that 4 bits in that location that a0 points to`

I get this error `timetemplate.asm line 115: Runtime exception at 0x00400158: address out of range 0x00000009`

Here is the updated code

```
time2string:
PUSH    ($t0)           
PUSH    ($t1)
PUSH    ($t2)
PUSH    ($t3)
PUSH    ($t4)
PUSH    ($t5)
PUSH    ($ra)           #nested subroutine must store $ra too

add     $t0,$0,$a0      #contaisn the adress of string (timstr)
add     $t1,$0,$a1      #contains the time-info(0x5957)

andi    $t2,$t1,0xf000      #check the 4 most signifaicant bits ignore other bits
srl     $a0,$t2,12      #shift the MSB to LSB position (hexasc take only 4 bits in the LSB position)
jal     hexasc      # call hexasc
nop     
sb      $v0, 0($t0)     #stor that 4 bits in that location that a0 points to

andi    $t3,$t1,0x0f00  #mask to get those 4 bits you and ignore other bits
srl     $a0,$t3,8       #shift those bits to the LSB position(0x000f)
jal     hexasc      
nop
sb      $v0,1($t0)      

li      t5,0x3A
sb      $t5,2($t0)


andi    $t4,$t1,0x00f0
srl     $a0,$t4,4
jal     hexasc
nop
sb      $v0,3($t0)


move    $a0,$t1
jal     hexasc
nop
sb      $v0, 4($t0)


POP ($ra)
POP ($t5)
POP ($t4)
POP ($t3)
POP ($t2)
POP ($t1)   
POP ($t0)

jr  $ra
nop
```

Comment: Please mark line 99. Also, check what address is being referenced by the instruction on that line, and figure out how it got the wrong value. Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code.

Comment: `lb      $t0, 0($a1)      #load one byte from a1     "LINE 99" ERROR` in tim2string function .

Comment: @Jester , @Ped7g,  please have a look to my updated version of `time2string`.

Comment: That means your `$t0` is 9, which is not a valid address. Perhaps you forgot to add a base address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    lb      $t0, 0($a1)      #load one byte from a1
```

This will load one byte from memory from address `a1`.

But `a1` does not contain valid address, it contains BCD time value, like `0x5958`, which is meant as time 59:58.

So you don't need to load the time value from memory, you already have the values in the `a1` loaded. You have to pick out each group of 4 bits separately (from low 16 bits), that's where the 4 digits are encoded.

---

Oh, and this:

> I have tried to run my code on MARS

That's not, how people are programming in Assembly. You don't RUN your code. You step over single instruction in debugger, one by one, verifying after each single instruction, that it did change only the registers/memory which it was supposed to change, and only in the way how it was supposed to change it.

*(that's why you need first English comments describing the algorithm, because otherwise you can't reason if the instruction did what you did want ... of course it will always do, what it does, according to the CPU docs, you will hardly ever in your life encounter the situation when the instruction itself fails to execute properly (although it's technically possible, when some electrons "jump" over the "walls" of supposed path, usually after being hit hard by some proton from X-rays/etc ... maybe if you will live long enough, it may happens once or twice near you ... it's very likely you will never notice, as the SW will probably survive it, or crash like it does normally from code bugs))*

Also make sure you avoid the brain playing tricks on you, taking shortcuts to save it's effort, so instead of your brain reading what is on the screen, it will try to tell you, what you did want to write and see there.

Like when you write in the code `sb $t0,0($a1)` instead of `sb $t0,0($a0)`, if you will try to re-read the source shortly after writing it, you will read `sb $t0,0($a0)`, unless you focus really hard and make sure your brain is not cheating you.

Same goes for debugging and checking resulting values in registers, etc.. if you for example expect value `1` in `t1`, and it by accident ends in `t2`, you may easily miss the the fact that the `1` did change in `t2`, not in `t1`, because your brain cares mostly that the result is `1`. Etc..

It's tricky. That's why people love Assembly, and code almost everything in it.

Comment: Ok, how about `sb` do i need to store byte or not ? then how to know which 4 bits i'm picking ?

Comment: You should produce values in memory pointed by `a0` (it does contain memory address of buffer, check task description), I don't see that in your code.The current `sb` is addressing by `a1`, which is of course wrong, as it is not address. You pick the 4 bits, which you do pick. If you do for example `andi    $t1,$t0,0xf`, you pick 32 bits of `t0`, clear b4-b31 (upper 28), and keep values in b0-b3 (lowest 4 bits), and store the result into `t1`. So that's how you did pick lowest 4 bits of `t0`. Apply this logic to pick bits of `a1` and adjust 0xF to pick others. And check "shift" instructions.

Comment: @ZERO another hint may be that the value `0x000F` in binary formatting is `0b0000000000001111`. And that if you shift value `0b0100` to right by 2 positions, you will get value `0b0001`. So write the main algorithm first like math formulas, consisting of basic simple operations (resembling asm instructions), in English comments. See how many distinct values/temporaries you need, allocate some registers to them, so you understand how your values are travelling through registers (starting with `a0=buffer_ptr, a1=time`). Simplify it (loop?). Finally write instructions doing the calculation. DEBUG

Comment: Thanks for quick and well defined answers,I'm new in assembly some topics i learned and some I'm trying. i will use your advices :).

Comment: @ZERO good, if you get stuck, or some advice is unclear, just ask... there are several more problems in your first code, as you will easily note over time, when you will debug it... for example calling subroutine will add some twist to your problems. :) You will know you are on the right path, when you will be capable on your own during debug to exactly describe what happened, and why it is not good for you. How to fix it may be not always that obvious and may take some time and reasoning, that's OK.

Comment: I have updated the `time2string` function please have a look.

Comment: @XERO looks quite good, like you understand what you are doing, but it doesn't work I guess... Re-read the ABI again, especially the part which registers you have to preserve and which are free to change. Your `push/pop` series are not needed, the `tX` are free to change, so only `ra` has to be preserved. But you are using many `tX` for yourself, and `hexasc` will damage `t0`. First you can reuse some registers a bit more, and either push/pop `t0` around `hexasc` (annoying), or rather `push/pop` at entry/exit one of `sX` regs, and use that one, as any proper subroutine shouldn't change that.

Comment: Thanks now it's working like a charm. i removed the tX push and pops also used sX register.

Comment: @XERO don't forget that you should preserve `sX`, so you should add `push/pop` instead for that one. Forgetting to do it with such simple example app, calling only your function, will very likely work, but if your function would be part of bigger application, the modification of `sX` would cause some failure in the caller code.

Comment: Yes i did it as you say. i pushed the `sX` on the stack to save them because those are callee-saved.